# JavaFX Dynamic label text

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How can I bind seconds to a property to make a label display text like "Left X seconds..."

```
label.textProperty().bind(secondsProperty)
```

just replaces whole text of the label to seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%s seconds left", secondsProperty));
```

You didn't specify the type of `secondsProperty`, but if it is a `DoubleProperty` (or other `NumberExpression`) you could also do

```
label.textProperty().bind(secondsProperty.asString("%f seconds left"));
```

Comment: So that's it, thanks! I assume there is no way to use label's text from fxml and just insert the numbers to it?

Comment: You can do [expression binding in FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding), but `secondsProperty` would need to be in the FXML namespace.